# How does Python execute the arithmetic operation if multiple operations are found in a single statement

Tags: python

I need to know how Python executes arithmetic operations. Below I have given some of the question. Please explain the concept behind this.

```
why 3+-+--2 = 1
why  3+-+-+--+++2 = 1
why 3-----------2 = 1
why 3--------+2 = 5
```

Comment: 3+-+-+--+++2 = 1 is not correct. 3+-+-+--+++2 = 5 . Check your tests please. Python executes the last operand and this is not really a stack overflow type question.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, could you please accept it? Your question is quite original and with an accepted answer it could be used as a reference for other similar questions.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable answer. I would have voded you if have enough points.

Answer (score 3):

When investigating such things, it helps to start small and advance from there. If you try these expressions one by one, it's pretty easy to see how it works:

```
3-2 = 1
3--2 = 5
3---2 = 1
3----2 = 5
```

Essentially, the first operation is applied to two operands, all other `+`s or `-`s are stacked on right operand as unary operations (as "positive" and "negative" conversions respectively). You can also use `~` operation (binary negative). There are no other unary operators in Python, so you're limited to these three (technically, `abs()` is a unary operation as well, but it's implemented as a function call instead of operator, so you can't stack it like this).

Internally, these operations are interpreted as calls to `x.__pos__()`, `x.__neg__()` and `x.__invert__()` special methods. See [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types) on special methods for more details.

To understand how such expressions are processed by Python, you can encase everything to the right of first operator in brackets and then use standard arithmetic rules to calculate:

```
3+-2 = 3+(-2) = 1
3+--2 = 3+(--2) = 3+(-(-2)) = 3+2 = 5
3--+2 = 3-(-+2) = 3-(-(+2)) = 3-(-2) = 3+2 = 5
```

Of course, if you find yourself writing expressions like `3+----+~+-2`, there's something **really** wrong with your code, but I assume your question is theoretical. :-)